# What are indexable types in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I was reading [indexable types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) and "dictionary" pattern confused me:

```
interface NumberOrStringDictionary {
  [index: string]: number | string;
  length: number; // ok, length is a number
  name: string; // ok, name is a string
}
```

```
interface StringArray {
  [index: number]: string;
}
```

What is the difference between the two?
How do you even initialize variable with the type of `NumberOrStringDictionary`? And why does `NumberOrStringDictionary`'s fields (`length` and `name`) depend on *index signatured* field?

How is `NumberOrStringDictionary` different from this:

```
interface SquareConfig {
  color?: string;
  width?: number;
  [propName: string]: any;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This type:

```
interface NumberOrStringDictionary {
    [index: string]: number | string;
    length: number;
    name: string;
}
```

implies that a value of type `NumberOrStringDictionary` *must* contain a property named `length` of type `number` a property named `name` of type `string`.  Additionally, a value of that type *may* contain *any* `string`-*named* properties, as long as the values of such properties are assignable to `string | number`.

A few points to clarify:

- Index signatures may not *conflict* with any other keys.  For example, the `length` property is of type `number`, so it is compatible with the index signature (`number` is assignable to `number | string`).  And the `name` property is also compatible.  If you tried to add a property of some incompatible type, you'd get an error:

  ```
  interface Oops extends NumberOrStringDictionary {
      acceptable: boolean; // error!
      //~~~~~~~~ <-- boolean not assignable to string | number
  }
  ```

  If I have a key of type string and I read the property at that key from a value of type `NumberOrStringDictionary`, what is the type of that property? It is `number | string`. Now imagine what would happen if you were allowed to add an incompatible property (like `acceptable: boolean`). In that case it would no longer be true. If the key I choose happens to be `"acceptable"`, then a `boolean` comes out which is not `number | string`, so something is wrong.  To be safe, you'd have to expect `number | string | boolean`.

  You can think of the non-index signature properties as being *special cases* of the index signature, where you know the property key definitely exists and that the value is of some possibly more specific type.  The known properties should be thought of as *particular/special* cases of the indexer.  "All properties of this object are of type `string | number`.  *In particular*, the `length` property of this object is of type `number`, and the `name` property of this object is of type `string`".  It's like saying "My pets are all dogs. Fido here is a poodle." Incompatibility would look like "My pets are all dogs.  Fido here is a parakeet".  You can *say* that, but it's not consistent.  You might be thinking of index signatures as a "default" or "everything else" or "rest" case,  ("My pets are all dogs *except* for this parakeet") but that's not what it means in TypeScript. There is an open issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867) asking for such a construct in the language, but it is not yet there (there are workarounds).
- An index-signature does not generally mean that *all* `string`-keyed properties will appear.  You are allowed to put as many or as few such properties as you'd like.  It is therefore possible that when you inspect a property of type `NumberOrStringDictionary`, it will be missing.  When you read such a missing property, you will get a value of type `undefined`, not of `string | number`, but the compiler will pretend that it is `string | number`.  TypeScript 4.1 introduced a [compiler flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess) to treat `undefined` as a possible result of any index signature property read, but it is not on by default.

---

Perhaps it would be helpful to go through some examples and see what is accepted and what is rejected by the compiler.  Here's a valid assignment:

```
const valid: NumberOrStringDictionary = {
    length: 1,
    name: "bob",
    someOtherKey: 123,
    someOtherKey2: "hey"
};
```

The requisite `length` and `name` properties are in there, and the additional properties match the index signature.  This is also valid:

```
const alsoValid: NumberOrStringDictionary = {
    length: 1,
    name: "bob",
};
```

because you don't have to add any such index-signature properties.  Now for the mistakes:

```
const invalid1: NumberOrStringDictionary = { // error!
    //~~~~~~~~ <- property "name" is missing
    length: 1,
    someOtherKey: 123,
    someOtherKey2: "key"
};
```

You can't leave out a required property.  Also:

```
const invalid2: NumberOrStringDictionary = {
    length: "fred", // error!
    //~~~~ <-- string is not assignable to number
    name: "bob",
    someOtherKey: 123,
    someOtherKey2: "key"
};
```

You can't put the wrong type of the required property.  And finally:

```
const invalid3: NumberOrStringDictionary = {
    length: 1,
    name: "bob",
    someOtherKey: 123,
    someOtherKey2: true // error!
    //~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- boolean is not string | number
};
```

You can't add a property that conflicts with the index signature.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.1.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIFcC2AjaB5KAZTClAHMARYBMYAexDigE9kBvAKGW+QG1QAJhAAeALmQBnEuQC64kFlxRkAH0nSQZANxceAGwiawAC3mLoOnskaYI4qaU06Avhw6hIsRCjx0ADhLIIpAgAoEYOPhEGpTUtAxMrJxWiEh+YHDYBuLYdHQGcCBayAD0JUFQUHRQAIS63GUAfs0tzcgAPAC0nci5+RCF1nRgyHASEsBkjFkoYHTqjmSq1uZQHK4cCAxSyABucHrAAuIRSgTEi1Q09IwsyAC87PXIBkamyACMADTPNnbIACJctgAT8rBI6LY8CZoABpCDMcQfABMAGYwTwIVCYVB4cxkeIAcYEQD1jpNtsRgcIQA1A5HE6rc4xK7xW6sR7JfSGMgmJEY7h-QnA0FktxbEA7UD7Q4CD6MyJQZmXOI3RIPdilcrQKq1Z5NVotDo9PxVPzQMCsAF-AHIYCBTD2iaaZ6vXnvb7PLEQaHE3EIpFogWSSE+nF4gmAgDWJLFEqlIBlR0jpyiF3IrLVd05rp5fMBMCgEAEoK1FV1dSsBraXR6DnIdsCIGGo3Gk2mBmQcxWit+cFswroIOD3t9cIDnyDXtDY-9+MJMeYpOc5PjI2l9IEqIVZ2iKuuCWzTysbvznqsQsBIpHM-DE5R6On2L9EfEJHQKDK5eqlZ41cNRq1r0eQFCAjZDCM9aaMsCi9iuHBAA)

Comment: I understand everything except, why `[index: string]`'s type should be compatible with the other fields' types? Is this just the way it is implemented in typescript, or am I missing something here? Could you, please, clarify this?

```ts
interface NumberDictionary {
  [index: string]: number;
  length: number; // ok, length is a number
  name: string; // error, the type of 'name' is not a subtype of the indexer
}
```
Why should the `[index: string]` property care about the type of `name` property?

Comment: If I have a key of type `string` and I read the property at that key from a value of type `{[index: string]: number; length: number}`, what is the type of that property?  It is `number`.  Now imagine what would happen if you were allowed to add an incompatible property (like `name: string`).  In that case it would no longer be true.  If the key I choose is `"name"`, then a `string` comes out which is not `number`, so something is wrong.  TypeScript enforces consistency here.  Does that make sense?

Comment: The known properties should be thought of as *particular/special* cases of the indexer.  "All properties of this object are of type `string | number`.  *In particular*, the `length` property of this object is of type `number`, and the `name` property of this object is of type `string`".  It's like saying "My pets are all dogs. Fido here is a poodle." Incompatibility would look like "My pets are all dogs.  Fido here is a parakeet".  You can *say* that, but it's not consistent.

Comment: I think you may be thinking of an index signature as a "default" or "everything else" or "rest" case,  ("My pets are all dogs *except* for this parakeet") but that's not what it means in TypeScript. There is an open issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867) asking for such a construct in the language, but it is not yet there (there are workarounds).

Comment: `The known properties should be thought of as particular/special cases of the indexer.` I had the - Aha, moment when I was reading it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Objects in JS can be thought of as a dictionary.
They can take arbitrary keys, which map to corresponding values.
This object - dictionary duality is also visible in syntax:

```
const o = {key: 1};
console.log(o['key']);
console.log(o.key)
```

Properties can be added and removed in runtime.

In general, most objects have a constant, known set of properties, and you model them as regular interfaces in TypeScript.

You need to use an indexed type if you want to model objects which follow JS rules

- can contain any property
- can be modified in runtime by adding and deleting properties

Note that there are 2 kinds of indices

- number - you can only index via a number (which means you use them like an array)
- string - you can index via any string (you use them like a dict)

In your example:

```
interface StringArray {
  [index: number]: string; // number index
}
```

```
interface NumberOrStringDictionary {
  [index: string]: number | string;   // string index
  length: number; 
  name: string; 
}
```

You define the variables of these interfaces as follows:

```
const myArray: StringArray = ["Bob", "Fred"];
console.log(myArray[0])

const d: NumberOrStringDictionary = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
  length: 2,
  name: 'myDict'
}

// You can add and remove properties in runtime
d.c = 1;
console.log(d['c'])
delete d.b;
console.log(d['c'])
```

Indexed types allow you to specify the types of values of the properties.

```
const d1: NumberOrStringDictionary = {
  a: true,  // error: Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.
  b: {},    // error: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.
  length: 1,
  name: 'myDict'
}
```

As described in the link from original post, if you add additional properties to a string-indexed type, the types of these properties must be compatible with the type specified for the index.