# what dose [index: string] mean in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm new to Typescript.  I saw the following code in one project on GitHub, What does it mean?

```
interface info {
  [index: string]: any;
}
```

Comment: You are looking for [indexable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65114590/what-are-indexable-types-in-typescript).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are indexable types in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65114590/what-are-indexable-types-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1):

It means an Object Literal (An object that is created using curly brackets  and can be defined by using `type` or `interface`, take a look at [this link](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781789345575/3/ch03lvl1sec24/what-is-an-object-literal#:%7E:text=An%20object%20literal%20is%20an,inherits%20from%20Object%20(uppercase).)) that accepts as pairs `index: value` of type `string:any`. Eg:

```
let example: info= {
  index1: "some index",
  index2: 1,
  // ...
};
```